# Unable to run .exe file created with Pyinstaller on AWS virtual machine

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyinstaller

This code:

```
with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as my_config:
    my_var = my_config.read().splitlines()
    
print(my_var)
input()
```

was converted to a .exe file using Pyinstaller.
When I run the .exe file on my local machine the program executes without any errors. Also, I am able to run the .exe file on any other virtual machine I have created using VMware. (As long as I have a file named "mytext.txt" in the SAME folder as the .exe file.)

However, when I try to run the .exe file on a AWS micro instance I get an error stating that "mytext.txt" can not be found even though it is present in the same folder as the .exe file.

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error on the AWS instance, but not on my local computer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On AWS virtual machines windows is configured to NOT show the file extension of files in explorer. When you name a file with an extension windows also adds an extension to the file, so instead of having "file.txt" in my program folder I had "file.txt.txt". This was the cause of the error.